# Can i make a random button?

Tags: java, button, random, imagebutton

I have a school project to make a game, I´m trying to make a memory game, but can only use the image twice, and need it to be random, here is what I've got so far. Don´t know how to use random for this specific thing, since the images while have to remain constant throughout the game and random makes that very difficult Sorry for the format, first post.

```
public class Juego  extends JFrame implements ActionListener{

JButton boton1 = new JButton();
JButton boton2 = new JButton();
JButton boton3 = new JButton();
JButton boton4 = new JButton();
JButton boton5 = new JButton();
JButton boton6 = new JButton();


public Juego(){
FlowLayout lay = new FlowLayout (); this.setLayout(lay); this.setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);



this.setSize(1080, 1080); this.setTitle("Memoria"); 




this.setBackground(Color.black);
try {
Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/videojuegos/media/card-back.jpg"));
boton1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
boton2.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
boton3.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
boton4.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
boton5.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));
boton6.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img));



 } catch (IOException ex){}
boton1.addActionListener(this); this.add(boton1);boton2.addActionListener(this);this.add(boton2);boton3.addActionListener(this);this.add(boton3);boton4.addActionListener(this);this.add(boton4);boton5.addActionListener(this);this.add(boton5);boton6.addActionListener(this)this.add(boton6);






boton1.setActionCommand("boton1");


 boton2.setActionCommand("boton2");



boton3.setActionCommand("boton3");



boton4.setActionCommand("boton4");



 boton5.setActionCommand("boton5");



 boton6.setActionCommand("boton6");





 this.setVisible(true);

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {






if ("boton1".equals(e.getActionCommand())){
    try{
Image img = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/videojuegos/media/card-back.jpg"));
Image img1 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/videojuegos/media/Fool.jpg"));
Image img2 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/videojuegos/media/empress"));
Image img3 = ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/videojuegos/media/lovers"));
boton1.setIcon(new ImageIcon(img1));
} catch (IOException ex){} 

}}}
```

Comment: Please do not ask us to do your homework.  Any specific programme questions you have are welcome but your assignments are supposed to test or teach you.

Comment: Just want to know how to randomize a button or any alternative. I don`t want you to make my homework, just answer that question.

Comment: What is your desired functionality?

Comment: Want to make a random from 1 to 3 once so I can make two cards the same Icon, the I just compare the two, I know how to use Random but don´t know which one to implement in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an `ArrayList` to hold the set of images and then use `Random` to transfer them to another `ArrayList` in a random order. For example:

```
Random rn = new Random();
ArrayList<Image> imageSet = importImages();
ArrayList<Image> randomizedSet = randomize(imageSet, rn);

public static ArrayList<Image> importImages() {
    ArrayList<Image> images = new ArrayList<>();
    // put some code here to add each image to images twice
    return images;
}

public static ArrayList<Image> randomize(ArrayList<Image> imageSet, Random rn) {
    ArrayList<Image> images = new ArrayList<>();
    while (!imageSet.isEmpty()) {
        images.add(imageSet.remove(rn.nextInt(imageSet.size())));
    }
    return images;
}
```

The `randomize()` method in this example will remove one element at random from `imageSet` and add it to `images`, doing so until `imageSet` has no elements remaining.